# Schedule run configurations automatically

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a Intellij Gradle Run configuration. Is there a way to schedule this to run automatically? The commandline that IntelliJ use to run this seems to be hidden so I couldn't simply make a cron job for this with command line.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in IntelliJ. If it's a Gradle configuration, the only IntelliJ-specific command line customizations are related to running inside the IDE, so you can simply create a cron job that would run 'gradlew name-of-your-task>'.